# How should I test if a PDU is too big in WinSNMP?

Tags: windows, snmp, winsnmp

I am building an SNMP Agent for a Windows application using the Microsoft [WinSNMP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Currently everything is working for single-item `get` and `set-request`, and also for `get-next` to allow walking the defined tree (albeit with some caveats that are not relevant to this question).

I am now looking at multi-item `get` and also `get-bulk`.

My current procedure is to iterate through the list of requested items (the `varbindlist` within the PDU), treating each one individually, effectively causing an internal `get`.  The result is added to the VBL, set into the PDU, and then sent back to the SNMP Manager, taking into account invalid requests, etc.

My question is how should I handle "too much" data (data that cannot fit into a single transport layer message)?  Or more accurately, is there a way to test whether data is "too big" without actually attempting to transmit?  The only way I can see in the API is to try sending, check the error, and try again.

In the case of a `get-request` this isn't a problem - if you can't return all of the requested data, you fail: so attempt sending, and if the error report is `SNMPAPI_TL_PDU_TOO_BIG`, send a default "error" PDU.

However, it is allowable for a response to `bulk-get` to return partial results.

The only way I can see to handle this is a tedious (?) loop of removing an item and trying again.  Something similar to the following (some detail removed for brevity):

```cpp
// Create an empty varbindlist
vbl = SnmpCreateVbl(session, NULL, NULL);
// Add all items to the list
SnmpSetVb(vbl, &oid, &value); // for each OID/Value pair
// Create the PDU
pdu = SnmpCreatePdu(session, SNMP_PDU_RESPONSE, ..., vbl);
bool retry;
do {
    retry = false;
    smiINT failed = SnmpSendMsg(session, ..., pdu);
    if (failed && SNMPAPI_TL_PDU_TOO_BIG == SnmpGetLastError()) {
        // too much data, delete the last vb
        SnmpDeleteVb(vbl, SnmpCountVbl(vbl));
        SnmpSetPduData(pdu, ..., vbl);
        retry = true;
    };
} while(retry);
```

This doesn't seem like an optimal approach - so is there another way that I've missed?

---

As a side-note, I know about libraries such as net-snmp, but my question is specific to the Microsoft API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RFC does require you to do what you pasted,

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3416

Read page 16.

There does not seem to be a function exposed by WinSNMP API that can do this for you, so you have to write your own logic to handle it.

Comment: I thought that was pretty much how it would be. I'm building the PDU, and if it's too much data I remove a bit and try again. Seems to work :) Cheers.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, net-snmp (linux) currently just gives up and doesn't respond if the PDU is too big. I wish it did what you are building; they would have to do it the same way. You can do some intense calculations of what you think the size will be, but you're essentially creating the packet to figure that out anyway. So the tedious loop isn't so bad.